# In Azure Mapping Dataflows has anyone been able to successfully change the escape character of a Source Dataset?

Tags: azure, csv, escaping, azure-data-factory, quotes

Has anyone tried this using the Mapping Dataflows?

Example input field is:

"This is a sentence, it contains ""double quotes"" and a comma"

The escape character is a " and the quote character is a ".

When I use a regular Copy activity this works without a problem, however
when using the same Dataset in a Mapping Dataflow it gets parsed into 2 fields instead of one. In fact changing the escape character makes no difference.

[image: Dataflow Dataset parameters]

Answer (score 0):

Closing this issue. I've realised that output still has the \ as the escape character so when opening the output file in Excel it appears corrupted